# Rails Server Error

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, installation, failed-installation

I installed rails on mac using Homebrew recently. I fired up the rails server using `rails s` but when I visit `localhost:3000`, I get the following error .

```
Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)

socket = socket.to_s unless socket.nil?

      connect user, pass, host, port, database, socket, flags
    end

    def self.default_query_options
```

I have googled enough but couldn't find a solution.

Edit:

I started mysql using mysql.server start . It started. But when I use `mysql -u root`, it gives the following error `ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)` . But in `localhost:3000` it gives this error `Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)` . And as far as I can remember, I didn't set any password for mysql .

Comment: This usually means that you are trying to connect to MySQL server on your local system and that either MySQL Server is not installed or not running. Did you install MySQL Server on your local system?

Comment: Yes, i did . `brew install mysql` . I just did that.

Comment: I am not well-versed with Mac instructions. Based on quick search, try following conversation here: http://macosx.com/threads/how-can-i-see-if-mysql-is-running.316694/

Comment: Also, how do I separately launch mysql using terminal in UNIX-based operating system ? and what's usually the default password? Need little help there .

Comment: When you install MySQL Server, it creates a superuser called `root` and asks you to assign a password. Did you not set any password? If not, then it creates it with an empty password. In order to access any MySQL server, you also need to install MySQL Client. Since I use Debian Linux, I get an option to install server and client separately, and I am not sure what options `homebrew` provides.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your terminal gives `ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`, then you definitely have a password in place. You have probably forgotten it .
Also, go to `config/database.yml` file and fill in your mysql username and password there if you remember.

Also, if you still dont get your password; uninstall using `brew remove mysql` and try the `.dmg` installer from oracle website.

Answer (score 0):

The error means that Rails can't connect to the database. It's likely MySQL is not running, or you misconfigured the `database.yml` file.

You wrote you installed MySQL via Homebrew. Homebrew doesn't automatically configure MySQL to start on system boot. This is explained in the output at the end of the setup, and also if you run `brew info mysql`

```
==> Caveats
A "/etc/my.cnf" from another install may interfere with a Homebrew-built
server starting up correctly.

To connect:
    mysql -uroot

To reload mysql after an upgrade:
    launchctl unload ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist
    launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mysql.plist
Or, if you don't want/need launchctl, you can just run:
    mysql.server start
```

Run `brew info mysql`, and follow the instructions to start MySQL manually, or configure it with `launchctl`.

You can test MySQL is running using

```
mysql -uroot
```

Also make sure to properly configure the `database.yml` file with the correct hostname, username and password. These values depends on how you (or homebrew) configured your MySQL instance.

Comment: I started mysql using `mysql.server start` . It started. But when I use `mysql -u root`, it gives the following error `ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`

Comment: It seems that you (or a previous) setup changed the MySQL default configurations. As far as I remember, by default, Homebrew installs MySQL with root without password.

Comment: There are several questions in SO about homebrew and MySQL. Check them, or start a new (more specific) question about that specific issue.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have started MySQL server by `/etc/init.d/mysqld start`.

`mysql -u root` produces the error you are talking about. It is possible to avoid this error by `mysql -u root -p` (yup extra p can sometimes solve your problem).

If this does not work then you can try this sequence of commands:

1. `sudo /etc/init.d/mysqld stop` *Stop MySQL server*
2. `sudo /etc/init.d/mysqld restart` *Restart MySQL server*
3. `ln -s /tmp/mysql.sock /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock` *For creating soft
   link between actual `mysql.sock file` and `/tmp/mysql.sock`*
4. `/usr/bin/mysql_secure_installation` *For secure
   installation of mysql. You can run this even if you have
   MySQL installed (for troubleshooting). It will prompt you to enter
   root password. Enter it, and for other options just type `n` for no.*